# Custom UML generator

Tags: python, uml, plc, twincat

I have been working on a proprietary industrial system for some time now, and just recently I was asked to make an UML-diagram of what I have done. However, I have worked on several hundred classes and functions, and do not wish to manually create this diagram.

This system is written in a very *exotic* language (PLC/Structured Text), not commonly used by programmers. The syntax, I'm told, is somewhat Pascal-like, and all files are saved in a collection of XML's. Each XML represent some kind of object, like functions, "function blocks" (essentially classes), "programs" (sort of like a static function), enums or structs.

These objects typically have a declaration and an implementation tag within the XML.

Parsing this type of code structure is not a difficult task using some standard XML-parser. Using a simple string matcher, I can classify each object and its relation to other objects. For the moment being, I have done this using Python.

My question is, assuming I know the structure of the code (object relations, etc), is there a tool or a programming library that may generate an UML diagram for me?

I am thinking something like [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/), however this does not seem to be able generate the [format I need](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Class_Dependency.png) in a simple manner.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.gravizo.com/) out?

Comment: This looks very promising, thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: You might use a tool such as `plantuml` or `graphviz` that generates uml diagrams from plaintext descriptions, if it is that easy to parse your structures, it should be almost as easy to generate the necessary output. But I think, for systems that large, automatic layout will most definitely fail.But personaly I doubt the sense of such complete diagrams. If the design is good, it should be possible to break it down into multiple smaller, fairly independant diagrams, that are easier to understand. If you need all in one, I think there might be graphical tools, that also allow a plaintext input

Comment: Indeed a complete diagram would be confusing. Eventually I do expect some "hands on" to get the result I want, but for the moment being an automated approach is what I need.

Comment: You might want to look at the [`UML 2.0 Diagram Interchange Specification (pdf)`](http://doc.omg.org/formal/2006-04-04.pdf) which should help you to import your generated diagram in various industry strength uml tools.

Comment: Besides the fact, that asking "is there a tool X" is off-topic, I would create this using Enterprise Architect using some script. However, automatically created UML diagrams are humbug. You need to express what you had done in a meaningful way. Documentation is no side product. It's the kernel of your work!

Comment: @ThomasKilian I do agree with you, however UML has not been a topic before now. Please note the context of the question: "I **have** X, is there a program that can help he achieve Y using X?", not "I am working on X...".

Comment: _is there a program_ is the OT point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be made using this website, using something like `dot` format (it is their specific format).

As an example, this code:

```
<img src='http://g.gravizo.com/g?
/**
*Structural Things
*@opt commentname
*@note Notes can
*be extended to
*span multiple lines
*/
class Structural{}

/**
*@opt all
*@note Class
*/
class Counter extends Structural {
        static public int counter;
        public int getCounter%28%29;
}

/**
*@opt shape activeclass
*@opt all
*@note Active Class
*/
class RunningCounter extends Counter{}
'>
```

gives this:
[image: class diagram image]

Answer (score 2):

If I can suggest Acceleo ? It implemnts UML2Text specification and is a tool to build generator from UML diagram and is an Eclipse plugin.

But your language seems so specific that it should be hard to find an existing generator.

Comment: Acceleo looks interesting. However, like you say, the language I am working with is terribly specific. It is commonly used with industrial control systems, sporting [Programmable Logic Controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller). Finding open tools for this environment is very difficult, hence my question.